# Sort stream of objects and get first and print out

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-stream

Im writing code to sort person list by age, and prefix to oldest one and print it

Defined list of objects:

```
    Person person1 = new Person(40,"John", "Smith");
    Person person2 = new Person(45,"Mike", "Well");
    Person person3 = new Person(68,"Bob", "Parks");
    Person person4 = new Person(49,"Leon", "Foo");
    Person person5 = new Person(30,"Christian", "Markus");

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(person1);
    personList.add(person2);
    personList.add(person3);
    personList.add(person4);
    personList.add(person5);
```

Im able to sort and add prefix it but the problem is to get first item and print it out

```
    List<Person> orderedPersonAge  = personList
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed())
            .map(s-> new 
    Person(s.getAge(),"Super"+s.getName(),s.getSureName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(orderedPersonAge);
```

I tried play with findFirst() ...

different way would be to sort by age, take the oldest one and than add prefix...

Comment: `I tried play with findFirst()` - and what was your problem?

Comment: failed on Optional ifPresent which as I assume need to be also included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do

```
Person orderedPersonAge  = personList
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed())
        .map(s-> new Person(s.getAge(),"Super"+s.getName(),s.getSureName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .get(0);
System.out.println(orderedPersonAge);
```

or

```
Person orderedPersonAge  = personList
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed())
        .map(s-> new Person(s.getAge(),"Super"+s.getName(),s.getSureName()))
        .findFirst()
        .get();
System.out.println(orderedPersonAge);
```

Comment: It works and follow my original path, My problem was that I have defined

            `List<Person> orderedPersonAge  = personList`
instead of

          `Person orderedPersonAge  = personList`

sorry for post formatting

Comment: Each of them is wasting resources, compared to a straight-forward `.max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))`, but using `.collect(Collectors.toList()) .get(0)` as in the first variant is maxing it out…

Comment: @Holger Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You might just be looking for

```
personList.stream()
   .max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)) // solves for sort with reverse and find first
   .map(s -> new Person(s.getAge(), "Super" + s.getName(), s.getSurname())) // map if present
   .ifPresent(System.out::println); // print the mapped output if present
```

Comment: This solution makes definitely sense for me but returns `Error:(40, 27) java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.StreamTasks.Person>` The reason might be `List<Person> orderedPersonAge  = personList` @talex proposed `Person orderedPersonAge  = personList`

Comment: @Paul this is just a `void` call since the action you wanted to perform was to consume the max-aged person.

Comment: Thank you for additional comment